# get the document id and default value from mongo aggregation function

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my sample document structure
    {

```
    id: "abc"
    config: [
        {
            feature_id: f1,
            properties: [
                {
                    id: 1
                    todo: "check the microwave"
                }
                {
                    id: 2
                    todo: "check the food"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            feature_id: f2,
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using mongoDb aggregation function to get `todo`  based on `feature_id`.
Tried multiple solution but it seems to fails

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([

    {$match: {
                "id": "abc",
                "config": {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            "feature_id": "f1"
                        }
                }
            }
    },
    {   
        $project : { "config": 1, "_id": 0}
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$configurations"
    },
]);
```

though I am getting the outcome , but it far from satisfactory.

the expected output

```
[{id: 1 , todo: "check the microwave" }]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the correct input document ( query fields doesnt match the document ) and also provide the expected output.

Comment: @Veeram : updated the question.

Comment: What is the criteria to select todo field ?

Comment: @Veeram: based on `properties.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use any of the below aggregation query in 3.4.

```
 db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"id":"abc","config.feature_id":"f1"}},
  {"$unwind":"$config"},
  {"$match":{"config.feature_id":"f1"}},
  {"$unwind":"$config.properties"},
  {"$match":{"config.properties.id":1}},
  {"$project":{"data":"$config.properties"}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```

OR

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
  {"$match":{"id":"abc","config.feature_id":"f1"}},
  {"$project":{
    "property":{
      "$arrayElemAt":[
        {"$filter":{
          "input":{
            "$let":{
              "vars":{
                "config":{
                  "$arrayElemAt":[
                    {"$filter":{
                        "input":"$config",
                        "as":"cf",
                        "cond":{"$eq":["$$cf.feature_id","f1"]}
                    }},
                   0
                  ]
                }
              },
              "in":"$$config.properties"
            }
          },
          "as":"pf",
          "cond":{"$eq":["$$pf.id",1]}
        }},0]}
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$property"}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([
    {"$match":{"id":"abc","config.feature_id":"f1"}},
    {"$unwind":"$config"},
    {"$match":{"config.feature_id":"f1"}},
    {"$unwind":"$config.properties"},
    {"$match":{"config.properties.id":1}},
    {"$project":{"_id": "$config.properties.id", "todo": "$config.properties.todo"}},
])
```